# Autocompletion in PyCharm not working. I've made sure the intepreter is pointed to my project and I've tried invalidating caches

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, interpreter

I remember autocompletion to be working for me on PyCharm some time ago, but I just noticed that is no longer is. It doesn't work for basic python syntax as well as any libraries.

I've tried using the "Invalidate Caches and Restart" option in the File menu of PyCharm. I've also made sure that the Project Interpreter is using the Python in the venv of the project created by PyCharm. I've tried a handful of other things but these two are the most common solutions I've encountered and nothing is working. Note that hitting Ctr-Space anywhere just gives me a "No suggestions" message (not sure if this is relevant but thought I'd mention it).

Any ideas? Any help or ideas at all are appreciated.

Comment: Does the Python syntax highlighting works?